# How to use Spark variables in all files using Pyspark?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I started to work with Pyspark in the last month.
I'm using JupyterLab and executing the codes only locally.
I was trying to write a project that uses Spark and Python but I started to have some problems with Spark variables.
When I say Spark variables I'm meaning these ones:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

conf = SparkConf().setAppName('local').setMaster('local')
sc =  SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession(sc)
```

[This is an example of directories in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETg0i.png)

For example, I have created the file SparkUtils.py to start Spark on notebooks without the need of the calls from conf, sc and spark commented before. This is working fine.
The problem starts when I want to use the spark variable in other files, for example, DataProviders.py with the code snippet:

```
 sku = spark.read.format("csv")\
                   .option("header", "true")\
                   .option("inferSchema", "true")\
                   .load(path_to_sku)\
                   .drop("_c0")
```

How spark was started in notebook, there isn't variable spark in the DataProviders function scope. If I was using Scala, I would build some trait and extends the DataProviders class to this trait, so the Spark context and features will be implicit. But I don't know how to do the same using Python, or if there is another way to do this.
The current way I solved the problem was that, when functions needs the use of spark variable, I simply added this line on each code:

```
  spark = SparkSession.getActiveSession()
```

But this is far from be the best solution, I'm repeating code and this is far from be the best practices also...
Somebody knows another way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SparkSession` is a singleton and thus `SparkSession.getActiveSession()` will typically return the same session every time you call it. I can understand the desire to avoid code duplication, but this is a short 1-liner that has a pretty clear behavior. I'm not sure if there are other issues with this approach, but it is usually fine to call `getActiveSession()` every time you want access to the `SparkSession`.

The most common alternative would be to define `spark` in one python module (aka a file) and import `spark` from that module in other modules.

For example, if `utils.SparkUtils.py` defines the spark variables, you can add the following to `etl.building.DataProviders.py`:

```
from utils.SparkUtils import conf, sc, spark
```

If you are coming from Scala, I would recommend thinking of each Python module as a rough equivalent to a Scala singleton `object`. It is a namespace in which you can define variables and functions that can be imported and called from other modules.

Comment: Your solution worked very well and you clarified to me the concepts in Python :)
Thank you very much for it!